# recovery data from php with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

ok I surrender .... I have 2 function very very easy but don't understand where is my error in php function ...
This is my php function

```
function chkstatus(){
global $mysqli;
//$cc=array();
$sql="SELECT  * FROM online WHERE id=".$_GET['idonline'];
$result=$mysqli->query($sql);
$row=$result->fetch_array();
header('Content-type: application/json');
/*$cc[]=array('value'=>$row['busy']);
$ccstr=json_encode($cc);
echo $ccstr;*/
echo $row['busy'];
}
```

And my javascript function

```
function chkstatus(){
var iduser=$('#idop').val();    
$.ajax({        
    url: 'chat.php?action=chkstatus',
    data:{idonline:iduser},
    dataType: 'json', 
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);      
    },
    error: alert("error")
}); 
setTimeout('chkstatus();',4000);
}
```

I have ever the error alert, and in console I haven't nothing! Any idea where I have this error???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is executing your PHP function. Solution one, call the function:

```
function chkstatus(){
    global $mysqli;
    //$cc=array();
    $sql="SELECT  * FROM online WHERE id=".$_GET['idonline'];
    $result=$mysqli->query($sql);
    $row=$result->fetch_array();
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    /*$cc[]=array('value'=>$row['busy']);
    $ccstr=json_encode($cc);
    echo $ccstr;*/
    echo $row['busy'];
}
chkstatus();
```

Solution 2 just run the code:

```
//$cc=array();
$sql="SELECT  * FROM online WHERE id=".$_GET['idonline'];
$result=$mysqli->query($sql);
$row=$result->fetch_array();
header('Content-type: application/json');
/*$cc[]=array('value'=>$row['busy']);
$ccstr=json_encode($cc);
echo $ccstr;*/
echo $row['busy'];
```

Your code also is open to injections. [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

You probably also want to `while` loop the `fetch`, otherwise you're only pulling one record.

Comment: you right... I forget to call the function ..... 10hrs of programming has this effect... sorry!

Comment: No problem, be sure to look into blocking injection hole as well.

Answer (score 1):

use this code in your server side code:

```
$row['busy'] = json_encode($row['busy']);
echo $row['busy'];
```

Please note first that is your function chkstatus being called when the ajax call is being made.

I hope this helps you.